# Get the last coordinates list from a text file

Tags: python, coordinate

I am reading coordinates of nodes (76 nodes). Basically I split the string of all coordinates. After splitting I have a result for coordinates of node, first number is the number of node, accordingly coordinates (x,y). Example:

['1', '3600', '2300']

I only want to get coordinates of node from 61 to the end node. I try to use the number of node by convert it into integer to compare. I don't want to delete the line "while line != "EOF" cause it shows up at the end of text file. How can I do it?

```
 def read_coordinates(self, inputfile):
    coord = []
    iFile = open(inputfile, "r")
    for i in range(6):  # skip first 6 lines
        iFile.readline()
    line = iFile.readline().strip()
    while line != "EOF":
        values = line.split()
        while int(values[0]) > 61:
            coord.append([float(values[1]), float(values[2])])
            line = iFile.readline().strip()
    iFile.close()
    return coord
```

Comment: What issue are you having?

Comment: Instead of `while ... > 61` , try `if ...`

Comment: oh no it doesn't work. When I print int(values[0]), it give infinite loop with value of 1. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You should use an if statement inside `while line != "EOF":` like so:

```
while line != "EOF":
    values = line.split()
    if int(values[0]) > 61:
        coord.append([float(values[1]), float(values[2])])
    line = iFile.readline().strip()
```

An alternate solution would be to read in the hole file then use list slicing to remove the first 6 lines and list comprehension to remove nodes larger than 61.

```
  with open(iFile, 'r') as f:
      coords = [ line.split(' ') for line in f]  # Read every line
      coords = coords[6:]  # Skip first 6 lines
      coords = [ [x,y] for nr, x, y in coords if int(nr) > 61] # Remove every node large    r than after 61
```